# Convert Milliseconds to date and time using MS

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, node-modules

I'm making a alt detection system for my discord server. and I'm making an Account Age here is the code for it. It sends milliseconds but the createdAt for other parts of the embed works but not the difference string. I'm using V13 Discord.js MS Node Package

```
const createdAt = new Date(member.user.createdAt).getTime();
const difference = Date.now() - createdAt;
```

Picture
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vk7Gl.png

Answer (score -1):

This might help:
if member.user.createdAt is already in DateTime format than

```js
const createdAt = new (member.user.createdAt).getTime();
const difference = new Date(Date.now() - createdAt);
```

Comment: How does this help? How do you get any sensible formatting for age out of it?

Comment: This might help in understanding 
const moonLanding = new Date('July 20, 69 20:17:40 GMT+00:00');

// milliseconds since Jan 1, 1970, 00:00:00.000 GMT
console.log(Date(Date.now() -moonLanding.getTime()));
// expected output: "Thu Feb 17 2022 10:41:17 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)"

Comment: When I tried that it shows this now. https://gyazo.com/1540940641d4180315bc8b47c5b8bc4b